# Displaying taxonomy term list within another taxonomy term

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have a vocabulary that list schools that users can select on registration and other vocabularies for books and courses, used on nodes.

Under each school's term page I would like to display a list of terms from Book vocabulary and other vocabularies and clicking on the any of the terms will list nodes with the term.

CT>Ucon

- Books

  - textbooks
  - fiction
  - animes

I have thought of using panel to display school terms and then place a block of the book terms in a region in the panel, but I'm not sure how to go about it especially the URL. I would like the url to look like uconn/books/texbooks.

Additional info: Craigslist has similar nested categories. You have city category then under each city you have sale, services, community sections. This is what I'm trying to achieve. I want each school to have their own sub-categories listed under them.

Answer (score 0):

Dee, I completely did not understand your question. But these code might help you.

```
/*To load a vocabulary*/

 $vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($machine_name);
 Example::$vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('book');

/*To get array of all term objects as a tree*/

$terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vocabulary);

/*To get children of all terms*/


foreach($term as $aterm) {

  $child = taxonomy_get_children($aterm);

}
```